# Generating a dropdown menu for unique categorical values in R Plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, visualization

I have a dataframe of tree diameter measurements that I'd like to visualize with an interactive scatter plot. There are a large number (>50) species in my actual dataset, and I'd like to be able to filter them to only show one species at a time. I've seen solutions where each menu option is hard-coded in the updatemenus argument, but this is less than ideal, as the number of species in my dataset is large and may change in the future.

I'd like to produce a plot similar to the static scatterplot generated by ggplot. Based on [this question](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-plotly-dropdown-with-variable-number-of-entries/149263/2) I have a semi-working example: it plots the data points and shows the species names in the dropdown menu, but when I select any of the species the chart does not update.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it seems like the dropdown menu is not linked to the dataframe?

Thanks in advance!

Sample code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(plotly)
library(rstatix)
####Generate random plot data####
set.seed(1)

df<-as.data.frame(c(1000:1999))
Names<-c('Spruce','Pine','Oak','Birch','Willow','Cherry','Fir','Larch')
df$Species<-sample(Names,size = 1000, replace = T)
df$Diam1<-(rexp(1000,1/40))
df$Diam2<-df$Diam1*1.02
df$Diam3<-df$Diam2*1.03
names(df)[1]<-'Tag'
head(df)

#Pivot data longer
LongDF<-df%>%
  group_by(Species)%>% #group by species
  pivot_longer( #arrange long rather than wide.
    cols = Diam1:Diam3,
    names_to = 'Year',
    values_to = 'DBH')


#Format year field as date
LongDF[LongDF=='Diam1']<-'2020'
LongDF[LongDF=='Diam2']<-'2022'
LongDF[LongDF=='Diam3']<-'2024'

LongDF$Year<-lubridate::ymd(LongDF$Year,truncated=2L)

head(LongDF)

#Static plotting with ggplot
LongDF%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Year, y=DBH))+
  geom_line(aes(group=Tag),colour='lightblue')+
  geom_jitter(width = 0.05)+
  facet_wrap(~Species,scales='free')

#Dynamic plotting with plotly
genDropdown <- function(NameList) {
  outlist <- list(list(
    method = "restyle", 
    args=list("transforms[0].value", NameList[1]),
    label = 'Species'
  ))
  
  for(i in 1:length(NameList)) {
    item <- list(list(
      method = "restyle", 
      args=list("transforms[0].value", NameList[i]),
      label = NameList[i]
    ))
    outlist <- c(outlist,item)
  }
  
  return(outlist)
}

UniqueNames<-unique(LongDF$Species)

plt<-plot_ly(data=LongDF, type='scatter', mode='lines+markers')%>%
  add_trace( x=~Year,
             y=~DBH,
             marker=list(
               color='lightblue',
               size=12,
               line=list(
                 color='darkblue',
                 width=2
               )
             ),
             showlegend=F
  )%>%
  layout(
    title= "DBH over time",
    xaxis = list(title = 'Year'),
    yaxis = list(title = 'DBH (cm)'),
    updatemenus = list(
      list(type='dropdown',
           active=0,
           buttons = genDropdown(UniqueNames))
    ))

plt
```

I've tried to implement a function which dynamically generates inputs for the 'updatemenus' argument. Ideally this would filter the plot to only display one species at a time, but selecting options from the dropdown doesn't change the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do but I'm not a master in plotly widgets.

```r
UniqueNames <- unique(LongDF$Species)
nspecies <- length(UniqueNames)

buttons <- lapply(1:nspecies, function(i) {
  visible <- rep(FALSE, nspecies)
  visible[i] <- TRUE
  list(method = "restyle",
       args = list("visible", visible),
       label = UniqueNames[i]
  )
})

plot_ly(data=LongDF, type='scatter', mode='lines+markers')%>%
  add_trace( x = ~Year,
             y = ~DBH,
             color = ~Species,
             marker=list(
               size=12,
               line=list(
                 width=2
               )
             ),
             showlegend = FALSE
  ) %>%
  layout(
    title= "DBH over time",
    xaxis = list(title = 'Year'),
    yaxis = list(title = 'DBH (cm)'),
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        type = 'dropdown',
        y = 1,
        buttons = buttons
      )
    )
  )
```

This works but at the initialisation all species are shown, I don't know how to prevent that?

Comment: Hi Stéphane! That works beautifully for my sample data; I'm not worried about it showing all species on initialization. Unfortunately, when I feed in my actual dataset (about 6500 rows and 54 species for now) I'm still having problems. All the datapoints appear on initialization, but when I select a species from the dropdown menu all the datapoints disappear and the X axis values shift all the way back to Jan of 2000. Does plotly have a limit on the number of datapoints or the number of options in a menu? I'll keep working with it to see if I can replicate the problem in a way that I can share